# Playframework form shows i18n keys instead of message

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3

I'm using Play Framework 2.3 and Twitter Bootstrap 3.2.0 for displaying my forms, and since PlayFramework comes with an helper that is not compatible with Bootstrap 3.2, I made my own form display, like this :

```
@defining(form("name")) { element =>
<div class="form-group@if(element.hasErrors){ has-error}">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="instance-settings-@element.name">Instance name</label>
<div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" name="@element.name" id="settings-@element.name" class="form-control" value="@element.value" placeholder="Enter a name for your instance" required />
        @element.errors.map { error => <span class="help-block">@error.message</span>}
    </div>
</div>}
```

This works really well except one key point, this line :

```
@element.errors.map { error => <span class="help-block">@error.message</span>}
```

Instead of having a message like "This field is required", I get : `error.required`
=> The key instead of the message.

I tried to switch to this, without any success.

```
@element.errors(element.lang).map { error => <span class="help-block">@error.message</span>}
```

Comment: I am stuck with the same problem too, did you get to find the solution for this issue?

Comment: Indeed, so I added an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally made it work, here's my solution :

```
@defining(form("name")) { element =>
<div class="form-group@if(element.hasErrors){ has-error}">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="settings-@element.name">Your name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" name="@element.name" id="@element.name" class="form-control" value="@element.value" placeholder="Enter a name" required />
        @element.errors.map { error => <span class="help-block">@play.i18n.Messages.get(error.message)</span>}
    </div>
</div>}
```

The key here was to (simply) to use `@play.i18n.Messages.get(error.message)`